# Conflicting lifetimes when using predicate returning reference (implementing "split at mut" with predicate)

Tags: rust, lifetime

Is there a way to assign lifetimes here, such that function like this can be implemented even for predicates returning references?

```
fn group_by_into_slices_mut<'a, T, F, K>(data: &'a mut [T], key: F, res: &mut Vec<&'a mut [T]>)
where
    K: PartialEq,
    F: Fn(&T) -> K + 'static,
{
    let mut data = data;
    while !data.is_empty() {
        let j = find_j(&data, &key);
        let (s1, s2) = data.split_at_mut(j);
        res.push(s1);
        data = s2;
    }
}

fn find_j<'a, T, F, K>(data: &'a [T], key: &F) -> usize
where
    K: PartialEq,
    F: Fn(&T) -> K + 'static,
{
    let current_key = key(&data[0]);
    for i in 1..data.len() {
        if current_key != key(&data[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    data.len()
}


struct Struct {
    key: String,
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![Struct { key: "abc".to_string() }];
    let res = vec![];
    group_by_into_slices_mut(&mut v, |e| &e.key, &mut res);
}
```

```
  --> src/main.rs:37:42
   |
37 |     group_by_into_slices_mut(&mut v, |e| &e.key, &mut res);
   |                                          ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 37:38...
  --> src/main.rs:37:38
   |
37 |     group_by_into_slices_mut(&mut v, |e| &e.key, &mut res);
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:37:42
   |
37 |     group_by_into_slices_mut(&mut v, |e| &e.key, &mut res);
   |                                          ^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the expression at 37:5...
  --> src/main.rs:37:5
   |
37 |     group_by_into_slices_mut(&mut v, |e| &e.key, &mut res);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so type `for<'a, 'r> fn(&'a mut [Struct], [closure@src/main.rs:37:38: 37:48], &'r mut std::vec::Vec<&'a mut [Struct]>) {group_by_into_slices_mut::<Struct, [closure@src/main.rs:37:38: 37:48], &std::string::String>}` of expression is valid during the expression
  --> src/main.rs:37:5
   |
37 |     group_by_into_slices_mut(&mut v, |e| &e.key, &mut res);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I was trying to add some lifetimes explicitly, including Higher-Rank Trait Bounds, but with no luck.

Playground:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1663e12bf67838dd0d1440f759a72b4e

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1:

I don't think it's possible without keeping `"abc"` as an `&'static str` like your current trait bounds require. If you can change your `Struct` object to this:

```
struct Struct<'a> {
    key: &'a str
}

fn main() {
    let _ = Struct { key: "abc" }; //never convert "abc" to an owned type
}
```

...and pass your closure as `|e| e.key` instead of `|e| &e.key` then your code compiles fine.

The function implementation doesn't change and the predicate still returns a reference but now that reference exists for `'static`. A `|e| &e.key` closure won't work because the returned reference is only allowed to exist for the body of the closure.

#### Solution 2:

Remove the `'static` bounds on both `F` traits and change the closure to `|e| e.key.clone()`, but I'm guessing that is not what you're looking for because you wouldn't be returning a reference anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want unnecessary `clone`. Regarding `'static`: it's closure's lifetime, not return type's, right?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean but the closure type would look like `|e: &Struct| -> &'static str { e.key }`. So the reference returned by the closure would have the `'static` lifetime. Did that clarify?

Comment: Isn't `'static` a lifetime of F, not K? Doesn't `F: Fn(&T) -> K + 'static` mean "closure `&T -> K` of lifetime 'static`"? In any case, removing this lifetime doesn't change anything. (It probably would if I passed a stateful closure.)